# Basic Ruby http server not displaying .jpg to localhost on win7?

Tags: ruby, http, windows-7, localhost

This [http](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) script works just fine from my gnome-terminal on Ubuntu (and per Aleksey, on Mac), but on win7, a small square gets loaded in the chrome browser. What do I need to do to get the JPEG sent through local host so it displays in the win7 browser? Per Holger's comment, I need to address the content encoding, but everything I've tried so far makes no difference on win7 (and still loads fine in Ubuntu without any explicit content encoding).  ?.

```
PS C:\Users\user_name\Ruby\http_test> ls
basic_http.rb
lolcat.jpg
PS C:\Users\user_name\Ruby\http_test> ruby basic_http.rb
```

```
# very basic http server

require 'socket'

def send_200(socket, content)
  socket.puts "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n#{content}" # <-- Correct? (Per Holger)
  socket.close
end

server = TCPServer.new 2016

loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
  request = client.gets
  if request.start_with?("GET")
      url = request.split(" ")[1]
      if url.start_with?("/images/")
        file = url.sub("/images/", "")
        picture = File.read(file)  # <-- initially Aleksey pointed out
        send_200(client, picture)  # <-- a variable name mismatch here
      else                         #     pictures/picture...      heh.
        send_200(client, "hello!")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

FWIW: Ruby 2.2, win7 & coding along with this [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZGPZua6xgA).

[image]

Comment: Your response is not valid HTTP/1.1. Line endings must be `\r\n` not just `\n`. Also, you are completely disregarding content encoding. The binary content of a JPG will probably not be valid as part of a UTF-8 string.

Comment: @HolgerJust, would this be valid HTTP/1.1 `socket.puts "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n#{content}"`? I will look into content encoding, your comment is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo in variable name.
You read file to `pictures`

```
pictures = File.read(file)
```

but you send it as `picture`

```
send_200(client, picture)
```

So you just need to edit variable name.

Maybe it would be a good idea to wrap request procession into `begin` block.

```
Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
  begin
    ...
  rescue => ex
    puts ex
  end
end
```

This way you can see if something goes wrong.

Comment: Hmm... well, addressing the variable name mismatch gets me a step further, but the lolcat.jpg image is not getting displayed, just a small square appears... ?

Comment: I have just tested it and everything works fine. What about another image? What is in html page source code?

Comment: That is encouraging. I'm going to switch OS to Ubuntu and see if it works there (currently on win7). Which OS and browser are you using? Thank you for your diligence!

Comment: Right now I am on Mac using Chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123945/discussion-between-aleksey-and-mr-kennedy).

Answer (score 0):

To get the jpeg loaded into the browser on a win7 system, the File.read command needs to explicitly address the binary content encoding, e.g. **`File.binread("foo.bar")`** per:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-binread

```
  if url.start_with?("/images/")
    file = url.sub("/images/", "")
    picture = File.binread(file)    # <-- Thank you Holger & Aleksey!!!
    send_200(client, picture)
```

Thanks to Aleksey and Holger!

Comment: Seems like you did a great job! I didn't know about such details so it is totally your victory.